# How to setup a customized DNS name for an Elastic Beanstalk App

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Beanstalk App which has a app_name.elasticbeanstalk.com domain name by default.

I want a domain name like www.app_name.com that can access by bowser, and take following steps.

1. Register the domain name app_name.com
2. Set `www.app_name.com` as a CNAME of the ELB's public DNS.

In this way, I can access the www.app_name.com by the browser.
But, once the browser is loaded, the URL suddenly changes to app_name.elasticbeanstalk.com

I do not want to show the `app_name.elasticbeanstalk.com` to anyone. Can I just use the www.app_name.com? How?

Help me please.

Comment: Just to be clear: The CNAME of www.app_name.com is app_name.elasticbeanstalk.com?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using [Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) and [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). To do this you would use the Elastic Beanstalk resource inside the CloudFormation template to create your Elastic Beanstalk stack. You would also use the Route53 resource to create your desired domain name. Then inside your Route53 resource you would create an alias that maps to your Elastic Beanstalk endpoint.

This might look something like:

```
"Resources" : {
  "DNS" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
    "Properties" : {
      "HostedZoneName" : "example.com",
      "Comment" : "CNAME alias targeted to Elastic Beanstalk endpoint.",
      "RecordSets" : [
        {
          "Name" : "example.example.com",
          "Type" : "CNAME",
          "TTL"  : "900",
          "ResourceRecords" : [{ "Fn::GetAtt" : ["sampleEnvironment","EndpointURL"] }]
        }]
    }
  },

   "sampleApplication" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
     "Properties" : {
       "Description" : "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby Sample Application",
       "ApplicationVersions" : [{
         "VersionLabel" : "Initial Version",
         "Description" : "Version 1.0",
         "SourceBundle" : {
           "S3Bucket" : { "Fn::Join" : ["-", ["elasticbeanstalk-samples", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }]]},
           "S3Key" : "ruby-sample.zip"
         }
       }],
       "ConfigurationTemplates" : [{
         "TemplateName" : "DefaultConfiguration",
         "Description" : "Default Configuration Version 1.0 - with SSH access",
         "SolutionStackName" : "64bit Amazon Linux running Ruby 1.9.3",
         "OptionSettings" : [{
           "Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
           "OptionName" : "EC2KeyName",
           "Value" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" }
         }]
       }]
     }
   },
   "sampleEnvironment" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
     "Properties" : {
       "ApplicationName" : { "Ref" : "sampleApplication" },
        "Description" :  "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Ruby Sample Application",
        "TemplateName" : "DefaultConfiguration",
        "VersionLabel" : "Initial Version"
     }
   }
 },
```

More information on using CloudFormation resources can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) and sample templates can be found [here](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/)

CloudFormation enables interacting with resources dynamically extremely easy and clean... no to mention completely scripted :)